# I got a small project on wireshark and I'm kinda stuck

Tags: networking, wireshark

Access the website and look at the packets you captured.  What TCP/IP protocol is used?  What are the two IP address that are interacting?
Did you capture any DNS packets?  What information did you get from those?
What other protocols were in packets from this interaction?  What information was on them?
The websites you should visit are:

https://www.cnn.com/
https://cway.cisco.com/support/

Can you help me out do this one? anyone?

Answer (score 1):

- Run the wireshark application.
- Open a browser and visit whatever website you want to.
- Go back to wireshark and you will see a whole bunch of network data and a textbox on the top of the window where you can apply a filter.

Applying a filter will help you limit your results to those you are interested in. A filter can be for example a protocol or a source/destination ip.

In your case, typing *http* and hitting enter, will filter the results to those associated with the websites you visited (because http is the application layer protocol used in that case).
Find the lines containing **GET / HTTP/1.1** as the info column and select them. You will see a list of all the protocols involded in those requests (in the middle section of the window). Inspect the protocol list and you will get all the information you need.

Respectively, applying a *dns* filter will give you a line with an info column like **A xxxx.cnn.com** and you can again inspect the middle section of wireshark's window to get the information you need.